# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useHistory) is not a function (React.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use **React Router Version 6** then I ran this code below:

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function Test() {
  const history = useHistory();
  history.push('/');
  history.replace('/');
  history.goBack();
}

Test();
```

But I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 ,
> react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useHistory) is not a
> function

Are there any mistakes for my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **React Router Version 6**, use **"useNavigate"** instead of **"useHistory"** which is **React Router Version 5**.

So replace your code (**React Router Version 5**):

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function Test() {
  const history = useHistory();
  history.push('/');
  history.replace('/');
  history.goBack();
}

Test();
```

With this code (**React Router Version 6**):

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

function Test() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  navigate('/');                    // Equivalent to "history.push('/');"
  navigate('/', { replace: true }); // Equivalent to "history.replace('/');"
  navigate(-1);                     // Equivalent to "history.goBack();"
}

Test();
```